# Y-axis Rotation for Image in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, kotlin

I'm asking about how can I Rotate (Y-axis) a picture in `ImageView` programmatically in kotlin or java for android Studio as showed below
I searched a lot.. Googled it.. but no answers
Here an example:

[image]

Another Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @iraj jelodari for guide me to improve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate your image on the Y-Axis, All you have to do is set this on your `imageView`. Keep in mind this is for Java.

`imageView.setRotationY(25);`

Your image will rotate just like you wanted, you can change the float value if you want.